# is there a way to use the curses svn client, or another tool, to browse a svn repository?

Tags: terminal, svn

HI,

I only have access to an ubuntu terminal for this task and I want to view a large SVN repository, then only check out a small part of it.  Is there a way to use the curses svn client, or another tool, to browse a svn repository?  I don't really want to check out hundreds of megabytes.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can at least list the contents of the repository directories using:

```
svn ls svn://example.com/svn/trunk
```

You can also do this with any directory in the tree, so you can use it to find the section you want to check out before doing a full-checkout of a directory.

If you need to look at any of the files in a particular directory, you can just checkout the files in that directory without recursing using:

```
svn co --depth files svn://example.com/svn/trunk/path/to/files/
```